# finishing activity on ProgressDialog's OnCancelListener does not work

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In my activity i load some data from a web service, during this i show a ProgressDialog to user ... i want the user to be able to close the Activity on pressing BACK D-Pad key.
I have done it as follows:

```
public class MyActivity implements OnCancelListener {
    /*  ...  */

    public void startDialog() {
        ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(
            MyActivity.this,    // Context
            "",                 // title for dialog
            "Loading...",       // message for dialog
            true,               // indeterminate?
            true,               // cancellable?
            this                // onCancelListener()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // I want to finish() this activity when dialog is canceled
        finish();
    }
}
```

You can see that i am finishing current activity in **onCancel()** method of Dialog's **OnCancelListener** interface. But this method is not called when i press BACK during the dialog is visible. The dialog disappears but onCancel is not called.

Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's android restriction. Try it using handler

```
public class MyActivity implements OnCancelListener {
    /*  ...  */

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

        @Owerride
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        switch (message.what) {
        case 1:{
            finish();
        } break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void startDialog() {
        ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(
            MyActivity.this,    // Context
            "",                 // title for dialog
            "Loading...",       // message for dialog
            true,               // indeterminate?
            true,               // cancellable?
            this                // onCancelListener()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
}
```